# Grails 2.3.6 IntegrationSpec Spock test can't modify controller.request.JSON when using @Stepwise

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, spock

I have an `IntegrationSpec` test in Grails 2.3.6, which creates an instance of any controller, adds data to the body (via `controller.request.JSON`), and then validates that it was properly set.

The problem is that when I add the `@Stepwise` annotation, it seems to lock the `request` object on the `controller` object. In the debugger I see it is the same object (based on the hashcode), and as you can see by the test failure below, the second time the test runs with a value from the `where:` block, it fails, because the first value from the `where:` block is still present.

```
@Stepwise
class TestSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    @Unroll
    void "changing controller request"() {
        setup:
        SomeController controller = new SomeController()

        when:
        controller.request.JSON = json

        then:
        controller.request.JSON == json

        where:
        json << [
                [one: "1"],
                [two: "2"]
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the failing message.

```
controller.request.JSON == json
|          |       |    |  |
|          |       |    |  [two:2]
|          |       |    false
|          |       [one:1]
|          org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest@55906c66
com.package.SomeController@7b044602
```

This does not fail if I remove the `@Stepwise`.

**Is there any way to force the `request` object to be recreated, or to override a value set by a previous test?**

Comment: I believe that controller.response.reset() in cleanup: in the feature method will also resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Never fails - an issue plagues me for hours, I post it here, and then figure out the solution.

So I looked into `IntegrationSpec`, which is a grails specific class to handle Spock Specifications in an integration environment. I noticed that the `setupSpec()` and `setup()` methods will initialize the request object by making a call to `initRequestEnv()`. Unfortunately, this only happens if this is not a test with `@Stepwise` - I'm not sure why.

The solution is to add this check manually in your test, by adding the following lines in the test, which will recreate the `request` object for each test.

```
private GrailsTestRequestEnvironmentInterceptor perMethodRequestEnvironmentInterceptor = null

def setup() {
    perMethodRequestEnvironmentInterceptor = initRequestEnv()
}

def cleanup() {
    perMethodRequestEnvironmentInterceptor?.destroy()
}
```